# Comparar Data Fim do primeiro registro com Data Inicio do Segundo

Tags: sql, query, firebird, firebird-2.5

Olá.

Estou com dificuldades para elaborar um SELECT que verifica se a Data Fim do primeiro registro da consulta **é maior que** a data inicio do segundo.

O banco de dados em questão é de apontamentos e por alguma razão, alguns apontamentos ficaram com a data inicio menor que a data fim anterior.

Para exemplificar melhor utilizarei os termos Atendimento, Pendência e Tempo, lembrando que um atendimento pode conter mais de uma pendência e uma pendência pode conter mais de um tempo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

A intenção é identificar quais tempos dentro de uma determinado atendimento que estão com a data fim maior que a data inicio do próximo registro.

Isso somente dentro do atendimento, ou seja, não pode ser comparado por exemplo a data fim do CDTEMPO 256261 com a data inicio do CDTEMPO 256269. Por que eles são de atendimentos diferentes.

Preciso de ideias de como identificar esses tempos. Não precisa ser necessariamente por SELECT, poderia ser por procedure também sem problemas. Neste select ou procedure preciso que fosse exibido os mesmos campos que a imagem acima, e retornar apenas o registro que possui a data inicio menor que a data fim do registro anterior.

Em teoria o select/procedure deveria me retornar isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: O que marca a ordem do registro ? Eu tentaria um join com a própria tabela , algo como chave=chave-1

Comment: Verificar eventuais superposições dentro de um atendimento ou dentro de um atendimento/pendência?

Comment: Em 17 não conhecia isto ou não me ocorreu ... LEAD e LAG https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-dml-windowfuncs.html

Comment: Caso que o perguntador "some" ...

Answer (score 2):

Nesta solução considerei **apenas dia, mês e ano**; para o restante do horário tem que seguir a mesma idéia pra implementar.
Os números de registros que tem data inicio menor que data fim do registros anterior retornado pelo método **VerificaDatas()** como String.

```
  private String VerificaDatas() 
  {
    String query="SELECT * FROM minhaTab WHERE 1";

    myCursor2 = myDBpesquisaData.rawQuery(query, null);
     
    myCursor2.moveToFirst();
        
    String RegistrosEncontrados="";     
    for (int i = 0; i < myCursor2.getCount(); i++) 
    {
 
            myCursor2.moveToNext();
            String data1 = myCursor2.getInt(myCursor2.getColumnIndex("DTINICIO"));
            myCursor2.moveToNext();
            String data2 = myCursor2.getInt(myCursor2.getColumnIndex("DTFIM"));
    
            Date Data1=date(substr(data1,7,4)||'.'||substr(data1,4,2)||'.'||substr(data1,1,2));
            Date Data2=date(substr(data2,7,4)||'.'||substr(data2,4,2)||'.'||substr(data2,1,2));
    
            if (data1-data2)<0{
                RegistrosEncontrados= RegistrosEncontrados+"; "+i;
                        
                            }
    }
    return RegistrosEncontrados;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar registro a registro passando a data-hora de inicio do atendimento e a data-hora fim do atendimento anterior. Todos os resultados que retornem (valor) >= (00:00:00) são registros que não solapam o horário do datafim - 1 com datainicio atual. Os registros que retornem (valor) < (00:00:00) são registros que tem solapamento de horário.

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE( "01/05/2014 09:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s" ), 
STR_TO_DATE( "01/05/2014 09:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s" )) diferenca

SELECT TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE( "01/05/2014 11:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s" ), 
STR_TO_DATE( "01/05/2014 10:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s" )) diferenca

SELECT TIMEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE( "01/05/2014 12:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s" ), 
STR_TO_DATE( "01/05/2014 13:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s" )) diferenca
```